# Does Volatility() method in MSGARCH package return standard deviation or variance?

Tags: r, garch

Simple question but I struggle to find an answer.
Does Volatility() method in MSGARCH package in R return standard deviation or variance?I am asking this question because I get strangely low estimates of Volatility() on my FitML model in comparison with standard GARCH or EGARCH models.

Comment: Multiply all your data by a non-unit constant, say $c=10,$ and rerun the code.  If the answers are multiplied by $c^2$ (which is likely, because GARCH models variances), then they are variances; if they are multiplied by $c,$ they are standard deviations; if they don't change (unlikely), then they measure relative changes and you have to research the package further.

Comment: I have found the answer.Volatility() function returns standard deviation.If someone wants to get the variance she/he should square the result of Volatility(). By the way, @whuber thanks for your hint.

Comment: Thank you.  Would you mind posting an answer to that effect along with an explanation of how you obtained the solution?